# How to connect remote Spring Boot App to ActiveMQ on Wildfly?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have to connect newly created app to ActiveMQ which is inside WildFly app server. I don't want Spring App to be inside WildFly server. It will run as standalone app on embedded Tomcat.
[image]
In Spring App I have added:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And now I want to connect like in documentation:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:9876
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

Of course I know that user, password and url are wrong but I really don't know what default values of java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory are, it's not explictly said anywere.

In `standalone.xml` it looks like this:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:5.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
```

and

```xml
<pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
```

I expect that I should add a port expose and enable some ?connector? over tcp to activeMQ so that I can connect remotely. Could you give me some advice what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the ActiveMQ embedded within WildFly is ActiveMQ [*Artemis*](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). Therefore, you should be using:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And since you're connecting directly to the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis and not looking up the JMS `ConnectionFactory` in JDNI then you can use the `http-acceptor` which is already exposed on port `8080`, e.g.:

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.broker-url=tcp://localhost:8080?httpUpgradeEnabled=true
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=secret
```

Lastly, I recommend you move to a more recent version of WildFly. Version 14 was released almost 4 years ago now. The latest release is 26.0.1.

Comment: Thank you, you brightened the whole thing up, and I even took a step forward (because I still have problems logging in but I think I can handle it). As for wildfly 14, I could remove all application servers for me, but this is the company's infrastructure :)